# Center Woocommerce star-rating element in Wordpress custom theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have successfully centred the woocommerce products on my page using css. However, the star-ratings div refuses to center whatever I do to it. I can change its colour and background, so I know that I am referring to the right element. Any help would be appreciated.

CSS:

```css
#top_rated_wrapper ul.columns-4 li.product {
  display:block;
  width:100%;
}

#top_rated_wrapper ul.columns-4 li.product a {
  text-align:center;
}

#top_rated_wrapper ul.columns-4 a {
  text-align:center;
  width:100%;
}

#top_rated_wrapper ul.columns-4 li.product img {
  object-fit:contain;
  object-position:center;
  max-width:100%;
  height:300px;
}

.star-rating {
  float:none;
  display:block;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}
```

The last class reference (.star-rating) doesn't work to center the element. '#top_rated_wrapper' is just my own wrapper around the woocommerce content. I have also tried a straightforward `text-align:center`.

Comment: Add your HTML markup as well.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding: 
1. check the visual scope of `.start-rating` class element, if it covers the full width, then 
2. check if the `.start-rating` class element has child elements then make them `display:inline-block` property. and add `text-align:center` in `.start-rating` class.

Hope it may help you.

Answer (score 1):

Very late to the party, but try:

```
.star-rating {
    margin-left: auto !important;
    margin-right: auto !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me!

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product .star-rating{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.star-rating {
  margin-left: auto !important;
  margin-right: auto !important;
}
```

Worked

Comment: Hi Tuhin, welcome to Stack Overflow! Would you mind editing your answer and adding a few words of explanation?

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is years old now, but none of the solutions above worked for me. I had to add `!important;` to everything.

```
.star-rating {
    float:none!important;
    margin-left:auto!important;
    margin-right:auto!important;
}
```

Hope that helps someone!